# Why is list[1:length(list)-1] okay but list[1length(list)-2] wrong?

Tags: r

a is a vector of string. I get an error if I use something else than -1 to try and get the values of the list.
Using :

```
 a[1:(length(a)-2)]
```

solved the issue.

```
a[1:length(a)]
[1] "ADE"    "DEZ"    "dfeefe"
a[1:length(a)-1]
[1] "ADE" "DEZ"
> a[1:length(a)-2]                                                                                                    Error in a[1:length(a) - 2] : 
only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Why is it wrong ?

Comment: It is due to operator precedence

Comment: try doing `1:(length(a)-2)` and you will see it will give you `1,2,3,4` if your length is 6, there is something called precedence. and parenthesis have to be evaluated first. otherwise you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is one of operator precedence. `:` has higher precedence than `-`.

`a[1:length(a)-2]` means `a[(1:length(a))-2]` rather than your intended `a[1:(length(a)-2)]`

In your case, `a` seems to have length 3, in which case `1:length(a)` is the vector `1 2 3` and `1:length(a) - 2` is the vector `-1 0 1`.

Also, even though `a[1:length(a)-1]` worked, it didn't work how exactly you might think. What you computed is `a[0:2]` (with the first index `0` simply ignored) rather than just `a[1:2]`.